# Parse the Excel file using C#

Tags: .net, excel

I want to use the C# to parse Excel file, like get data from it.

I Google it on net, find most of them use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0. This program would run a x64 Windows 2008 server. But the Jet engine is not available for x64 and no longer used. Is there any way to do it?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is an Excel compatible spreadsheet component for .NET which works with 32 bit and with 64 bit applications (one of the great features of .NET is building one executable which works fine with both). With SpreadsheetGear you can load Excel workbooks, get underlying the data of a cell (number, text, etc...), get formatted text of a cell, recalculate, etc...

You can find live ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

Search for BIFF8. This is the format for Excel 97-2003.

"Excel Data Reader - Read Excel files in .NET" at 
http://www.codeplex.com/ExcelDataReader

"Create Excel Workbook (BIFF8) without having Excel Installed (Updated)" at http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=6887

.NET Managed Reader for Microsoft® Excel at http://xport.mvps.org/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a C# conversion of JExcelApi floating around somewhere that works.